# Oracle Apex pass multiple Values to another page

Tags: hyperlink, apex, card

I want to pass the value of two items from an sql select to two page items in another page within my CARD_LINK. I want to do this with the apex.page.get_url() function.
It looks like:
apex_page.get_url(p_page => 360, p_items => 'P360_PERSON_ID,P360_PERSON_TYPE', p_values => 'e.id,e.type') CARD_LINK

That's the recommended way to do this, but in the other page (360) the values for the items are e.id and e.type, not the real values given by the sql select.

Does anybody know help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
apex_page.get_url( 
  p_page => '11', 
  p_clear_cache => '11', 
  p_items => 'p11_id,p11_parent_id', 
  p_values =>  table.id||','||parent_table.id 
) as some_link
```